# Retrieve data from Redis in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, redis

I have just discovered how cool node js is and was looking at options for persisting.  I saw that you could use redis-client to store data in redis and I have been able to store data ok, like so:

```
var redis = require('redis-client');

var r = redis.createClient();

var messege = {'name' => 'John Smith'};

var type = "Contact";

r.stream.on( 'connect', function() {
  r.incr( 'id' , function( err, id ) {
    r.set( type+':'+id, JSON.stringify(messege), function() {
      sys.puts("Saved to redis");
    });
  });
});
```

This store a key with a json string as the value.  I am however trying to retrieve all the keys from redis and loop around them.  I am having trouble figuring out the way to do this, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Eef

Comment: You may want to look into the redis2JSON module. It may make things easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get keys from redis, you should use the `.keys` parameter. The first parameter that you pass is a 'filter' and `.keys` will return any items matching the filter.

For example `r.keys('*', ...)` will return all of the keys in redis as an array.

Here's the documentation on this command: http://redis.io/commands/keys

To loop through them, you can just do a simple `for in` as follows:
    `r.keys('*', function (keys) {
        for (key in keys) {
           console.log(key);
        }
     });`

Comment: ah gotcha. thought it would be something simple like that. total brain freeze. thanks!

Comment: No prob! I didn't try this code out before writing it, so let me know if you have any issues with it, I'm happy to take a look :)